# PHP/Jquery - Rickshaw chart data output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdo, rickshaw

I am trying to add data to my Rickshaw chart. The format is like this:

```
var data = [ { x: 1910, y: 92228531 }, { x: 1920, y: 106021568 }, { x: 1930, y: 123202660 }, { x: 1940, y: 132165129 } ];
```

However, I want to add data from my database:

First, I add all my data to an empty array:

```
$data = array();
$days = array();
```

Then I loop my data, for the past 90 days:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 89; $i++) {
    $days[$i] = date('d-m', strtotime('-' . ($i + 0) . ' day'));
 }
for($x = 0; $x <= 89; $x++){ 
$queryE = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM xeon_users_rented WHERE id=:user");
$queryE->bindParam(":user",$referralId);
$queryE->execute();

$row=$queryE->fetch();
$data[] = ($row['clicks'.$x.''] > 0 ? $row['clicks'.$x.''] : 0);

}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 89; $i++) {
  $days[$i] = date('d-m', strtotime('-' . ($i + 0) . ' day'));
}
```

However, I am in doubt on how to add above data to my Rickshaw chart? How can I output the above array in this format:

```
var data = [ { x: $data, y: $days } ]
```

Comment: I see much that can be done, but where's "$referralId" coming from for starters? Is it always the same id or different?